# Most liked item from last 7 days?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore for my app and would like to be able to get the most liked item posted within the last 7 days. In an ideal world the call would look something like:

```
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
        let start = calendar.date(from: components)!
        let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: start)!
        let startDateStamp: Timestamp = Timestamp(date: startDate)

        let mostLiked = colRef
        .whereField("isReported", isEqualTo: false)
        .whereField("timestamp", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startDateStamp)
        .order(by: "likeCount", descending: true)
        .limit(to: 1)

        mostLiked.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error { return }
            guard let snap = snapshot else { return }

            for document in snap.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                print(data)
            }
        }
```

But this is obviously not allowed.

I have ended up with:

```
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: Date())
        let start = calendar.date(from: components)!
        let startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: start)!
        let startDateStamp: Timestamp = Timestamp(date: startDate)

        let mostLiked = colRef
        .whereField("isReported", isEqualTo: false)
        .whereField("timestamp", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startDateStamp)
        .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)

        mostLiked.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error { return }
            guard let snap = snapshot else { return }

            for document in snap.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                ...
                 data handling code to fill struct - newTopItem
                ...

                if self.topLikedArray.isEmpty {
                    self.topLikedArray.append(newTopItem)
                } else {
                    if likeCount > self.topLikedArray[0].likeCount! {
                        self.topLikedArray.removeAll()
                        self.topLikedArray.append(newTopItem)
                    }
                }
            }
           print("Top Item: \(self.topLikedArray)")
        }
```

Which fetches everything within the last 7 days and I'll have to manually sort through to get the max likeCount, which seems a little clumsy to me not to mention the scalability issue it presents as I can't limit the results to just 1. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Seems like you have >90% of the solution in place.  Since you want the most liked, you do not need to order by timestamp, but you want to keep the order by likeCount. Your most liked item will always be the first item, so you can then retrieve only one item instead of all of them.

Comment: That is not allowed by Firestore though. Due to the whereField clause on Timestamp for the last 7 days, the first order clause must be against the timestamp field.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let mostLiked = bleatsRef
        .whereField("isReported", isEqualTo: false)
        .whereField("timestamp", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startDateStamp)
        .order(by: "likeCount", descending: true)
        .limit(1)

    mostLiked.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        guard
            error == nil, 
            let snap = snapshot 
            else { return }

        print("The most liked document is: \(snap.documents.first)")
    }
```